How do I make eslint/TypeScript infer an Angular signal value for an if clause?
I am trying to use a signal value that can be undefined, but I am stumped on how to tell the linter that the value is defined after I check that it actually is defined.
Example
export class MyComponent {
  mySignal$: WritableSignal<{ msg: string } | undefined> = signal(undefined);

  constructor() {
    this.mySignal$.set({ msg: 'Hello there!' });

    effect(() => {
      if(this.mySignal$()) {
        console.log(this.mySignal$().msg) // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
        
        // Works but feels like there should be an easier way
        // console.log((this.mySignal$() as { msg: string }).msg)
      }
    });
  }
}

Relevant Installed Packages
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.3"
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.3"
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.3"
"@nx/eslint-plugin": "16.8.1"
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.60.1"
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.60.1"
"eslint": "8.46.0"

Edit 1
I have simplified my real code to the example a little too much, not showing the full problem. But I will still be using the Not Null Assertion from Narens answer.
export class MyComponent {
  msgSignal$: WritableSignal<{ msg: string } | undefined> = signal(undefined);
  resultSignal$: WritableSignal<string | undefined> = signal(undefined);

  constructor() {
    this.msgSignal$.set({ msg: 'Hello there!' });
    this.resultSignal$.set('General Kenobi');

    effect(() => {
      if(this.msgSignal$() && this.resultSignal$()) {
        this.msgSignal$().msg = this.resultSignal$() // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
    
        // Fix
        // this.msgSignal$()!.msg = this.resultSignal$()!
      }
    });
  }
}


We can use either TypeScript Not Null Assertion (!.) or Typescript Safe Navigation Operator (?.) to bypass this error!
TypeScript error will be shown because you have defined the type as { msg: string } | undefined. So there is a possibility for the variable to be undefined, when we access a property of an undefined value, exception will happen.
TypeScript warns this, so we can assert that it won't be null using !., but I think for this particular scenario ?. is the best solution, because it will handle the undefined scenarios.
TypeScript Playground -> check how TypeScript converts to JS
import { Component, WritableSignal, effect, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  mySignal$: WritableSignal<{ msg: string } | undefined> = signal(undefined);

  constructor() {
    this.mySignal$.set({ msg: 'Hello there!' });

    effect(() => {
      if (this.mySignal$()) {
        // console.log(this.mySignal$()!.msg); // or this
        console.log(this.mySignal$()?.msg); // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

        // Works but feels like there should be an easier way
        // console.log((this.mySignal$() as { msg: string }).msg)
      }
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you, I'll use the Not Null Assertion. I have previously disabled it in my .eslint.json since I had the notion that this was bad practise. But this seems like a real valid usecase for it. My non-example code had a little more complicated usecase that better suits this, I had simplified it too much for my example.
